# Python package naming convention

Tags: python, package

I want to create some python packages and deploy them in my company, not on PyPi.

I stumbled over the problem that one package name already existed. So instead of mypackage from our repo I installed a PyPi package.

The obvious solution is to change the name of the package. However, if I don't put the package on PyPi, there are chances somebody will place another package with that name.

I currently see two options. Create a dummy package and put it on PyPi to reserve the name. Or use something like a namespace.

I read about PEP 423, which propose this idea, but it seems not to be agreed on.

Is it anyway a good idea to use this? How would I do it? company.package or company_package? Both are not confirming to PEP 8.

Or is there another way?

Edit:
Playing around with different name spaces I observed the following:

1. Having a dot in the name is really a bad idea, as it seems not to work.
2. Underscore does work with one minor annoyance. To install one must run `pip install my-package` and for import it's `import my_package`.

Comment: "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!" - Tim Peters

Comment: Do you have a specific strategy in mind for "using something like a namespace"? Do you actually want to publish the package on PyPI later?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel as said: I will not publish it on PyPi because it contains business secrets. I gave an example like company.package.

Comment: You can install local packages using a separate `pip install --no-index` call that ignores PyPi.

Comment: @chepner I don't know if that would work out. Pip is already configurated to look at the local repo which can forward requests to pypi. I guess I will stick with the namespace solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't squat on a name with an empty project. You have already proven your project may have names that are somewhat common *"one package name already existed"*.

According to [PEP541](https://peps.python.org/pep-0541/#invalid-projects) (which was [accepted](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2018-March/032089.html)), Your project would be **invalid** and considered for removal.

> A project published on the Package Index meeting ANY of the following is considered invalid and will be removed from the Index:
>
> ...
>
> project is name squatting (package has no functionality or is empty);
>
> ...

Instead, use a namespace as you already mentioned.

Comment: What is the recommended scheme to name the package in that case?

Comment: @FordPrefect that's more of a matter of opinion really... I'd follow whatever you already do internally over any other specific recommendations, or if you don't have an internal naming convention already defined; start now, and make sure everyone uses it going forward. [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces) has some guidance: `<Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]`, as do many other companies...